# how to embedding google doc link in email sent by airflow

Tags: airflow

I am using the below emailoperator in airflow to send emails that can be embedded with google sheet link nicely. however, i only can receive the email with congrats.

```
email = EmailOperator(
    task_id='email',
    to='aa@gmail.com',
    subject='test dag done',
    html_content="Congrats.<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/Ts94ZwN11UAyY/edit?usp=sharing' noborder='0' width='95%' height='600' scrolling='yes' seamless></iframe>",
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS
)
```

Not sure how to embed the google link in the email?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to embed an iframe into a mail - which is NOT supported by most clients/mail providers, i.e. [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/en/help/limitations-of-html-email/) states:

> An  (inline frame) is an HTML element that embeds content from
> one website into another. Inline frames are often used to insert
> advertisements, video, audio, or forms in other websites. Iframes
> often contain scripts, so most email clients block them.
>
> Instead, link to the content you want to display in your campaign.

If you just want to embe a link, and not the document itself, you can use `<a href>`, i.e.

```
<a href='https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/Ts94ZwN11UAyY/edit?usp=sharing'>Google Doc Link</a>
```